# How to use Hibernate to cache table data and speed-up queries?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, caching, jpa

I am using Hibernate 4, JSF, and Spring in my project.

I have tables like: `ValidStatus`, `Valid Group`, `ValidAccess`, in which I already populated some default data.

I have to put all these tables data in the Cache so that, anytime in different pages, I can use these table for authorizing users.

How can we cache these table data? Do I have to use the Second-Level Cache for this scenario or something else will work as well?

Answer (score 2):

The first level cache is only valid for as long as the current running `Session` (a.k.a `EntityManager`) is open.

Two concurrent transactions will run in different `Session`(s), hence each one will have it's own 1st Level Cache, which is not what you aim for.

You want the [2nd Level Cache](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-does-hibernate-store-second-level-cache-entries/), which is shared between concurrent `Session`(s):

- [EhCache](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-does-hibernate-read_write-cacheconcurrencystrategy-work/) is a very well-known 2nd Level Cache implementation,
- [Infinispan](http://infinispan.org/) which is developed by Red Hat.

Comment: Thanks any gud Example how to integrate with JSf+Spring Application?

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate has default cahching capability.

Hibernate first level cache is Session level cache, so if the object is currently in the Hibernate session results will be fetched from it.

Therefore, yoou do not need to cache fetched results, it is already cached by hibernate.

**See also**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20369520/892994

[Hibernate Caching](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch06.html)

Comment: But i want only Valid table data be in Cache not every table or query data store in Cache